# Parse.com/Unity: What is the point of using ContinueWith for task results vs. yielding a coroutine while task is not complete?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parse-platform, task, coroutine

I was wondering about it ever since I saw code samples in the [Parse Unity guide](https://parse.com/docs/unity_guide#queries). They recommend to do every operation where you need to access results this way:

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("ClassName").WhereEqualTo("fieldName", fieldValue);
query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;
    // Do stuff with results
});
```

Of course, the contents of those brackets effectively go into a different thread, which is not very convenient for many reasons (especially in Unity, where lots of operations are restricted to main thread). So, I was wondering whether I can get the results of a task without actually using ContinueWith.

And, uh, unless I'm terribly misunderstanding something, that actually seems simple to do. Why not use a coroutine with this?

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("ClassName").WhereEqualTo("fieldName", fieldValue);
var queryTask = query.FindAsync();
while (!queryTask.IsCompleted) yield return null; 
IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;
// Do stuff with results
```

Both examples exclude obvious checks for queryTask.IsCanceled and queryTask.IsFaulted, but you get the idea. Now you have your results on the main thread with all the wonderful conveniences that entails.

So, my questions are:

- Am I making some horrifying mistake by using the second approach? Seems to work in my builds, but who knows, maybe I'm overlooking something important beyond "wow, it's not crashing".
- If there is nothing specifically wrong about the second approach, are there any reasons to use the first one still? Maybe it's better for some particular use cases, outweighing the convenience of doing operations over results on the main thread?

P.S.: I'm aware of Loom framework, it's frequently mentioned in Parse-related threads as a convenient way to dispatch things to the main thread. I know that I can use it to dispatch anything that requires the main thread, like logging or operations on game objects using it. But I'm not sure if I actually need ContinueWith at all - if more simple implementation works well too, simple is probably better.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this, and why ContinueWith > Yield?